# How to let an openvpn client access to another client's subnet?

Tags: openvpn

My network topology:

[image]

Sorry to ask again here, I'v post this question in StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047558/how-to-let-an-openvpn-client-access-to-another-clients-subnet

The system informed me to post here.

I want all clients in OpenVPN network 10.8.0.0/24 can access to a subnet behind 10.8.0.3

I don't want to do any manully configurations in OpenVPN clients other than 10.8.0.3

I googled lots of solutions, but can't find one meet my demand.

I know it's not easy, so I'm willing to pay for your solution.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: This is impossible, as it will require configuration of the remote network's routing rules and of the remove OpenVPN client's network stack.

Comment: Sorry I can't do any reply now, because I'm still trying.

Answer (score 1):

You would maybe be able to accomplish this if you can change the client on `10.8.0.3` to a server install of PFsense. Then you could do a site-to-site OpenVPN tunnel. This should allow you to get the routes in place for both ends of that tunnel.

You would also have to add a route on `192.168.1.1` pointing the networks that need a route back towards the next hop `192.168.1.2`.

https://docs.openvpn.net/how-to-tutorialsguides/virtual-platforms/site-to-site-layer-3-routin-using-openvpn-access-server/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but I think it's easier if the router you use for the Internet gateway is also the same router than handles the VPN, that way, you don't have to configure anything on the laptops, on either side.  An Ubuntu laptop on both ends will work, but it's not as plug and play for vpn use on all the computers on the network.

Get 2 soho (most are wireless) routers that will run OpenWRT and have gigabit ethernet.  The new style linksys would be perfect.  I get 12mbps between sites, limited by the upload on comcast cable, but that's still pretty good.  If you have fios it will be even better.

You should Google and read about "site to site openvpn" and accessing "openvpn client subnets", and "pushing routes" should get you the info you want.  Understand it before jumping in.

First off, never use anything in the 192.168.1.0 subnet anywhere in your network once you plan to do a vpn, it's too common and can cause issues if you ever let laptops remote into the VPN server.  Use 10.123.123.0 or 192.168.10.x

Keep in mind, for this example, each location has a different subnet of ip addresses, and so does the VPN itself for the routers to talk, so a 3rd subnet.  The IP range of the subnets don't have to resemble each other, but it makes it easier to remember if they have some sort of scheme.

Basically, setup one site router as an openvpn server, and the other router as a client.  Make the better Internet connection the server for future expansion if you want a 3rd site.

Location New York
Public 128.111.222.123
openVPN server 10.99.0.1
LAN subnet 10.99.1.1

Location Boston
Public 124.132.129.213
OpenVPN client 10.99.0.2
LAN subnet 10.99.2.1

If configured correctly, Boston laptop 10.99.2.185 can ping new york laptop 10.99.1.236 without any config on the laptop whatsoever.  You could also easily (at this point) allow road users to install the openvpn client to get (example) 10.99.0.101 address, which can ping either Boston or new York subnet.

It's all free!